Issues in Parallel Execution: Manage Selenium WebDriver sessions when Injecting Page Object implementations with Java Spring Cucumber
I need to inject different PageObject implementations depending on some property, but faced a problem with managing WebDriver sessions.
@Configuration
    public class WebDriverConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope("browserscope")
    @Documented
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "browser", havingValue = "chrome")
    public WebDriver chromeDriver(){
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
    }

I am using Cucumber to launch my tests and it's working as expected when I run a single cucumber scenario, but when I run them in parallel, the values from one Thread are being used in another Thread
This is how my step definition class looks like
@SpringBootTest
    @CucumberContextConfiguration
    @Scope("cucumber-glue")
    public class CPLSteps {

    }

I am using testng to lauch my cucumber Features in parallel
    import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
    import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
    import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
    import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;



    @CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "com.intact.contactpl.web.ui.bdd",
        tags = "@smoke",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/index.html",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"
        },
        monochrome = true
    )
    public class FeatureParallelTest {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) throws          Throwable{
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        if (testNGCucumberRunner == null) {
            return;
        }
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

    }

Not sure what I am doing wrong, how can I manage the sessions properly ??
Example of my page object class:
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER,       ElementType.FIELD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @Component
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Documented
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public class Login extends BasePageObject {

      @FindBy(id = "username")
      private WebElement txt_username;
      @FindBy(id = "password")
      private WebElement txt_password;
      @FindBy(id = "login-btn-label")
      private WebElement btn_login;
      @Value("${internalURL}")
      private String URL;

      public Login openLoginPage(String url) {
      this.driver.get(url);
      return this;
     }
    

I tried adding @Scope("cucumber-glue") to the Step definition class but it didn't helped me to fix my issue.

Try making the web driver and all it's dependents scenario scoped.

I tried that but it's not working, for example as shown below:  Keys sent to the web element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (d11735e5f99de040d2f6ec5549b38811)] -> id: fld_civicNumber_client10] with value: 40 Current Thread: TestNG-PoolService-2 Keys sent to the web element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (d11735e5f99de040d2f6ec5549b38811)] -> id: fld_civicNumber_client10] with value: 40 Current Thread: TestNG-PoolService-1. Here eventhough it says it's using two different threads, but on the UI, the values are set to the same field as 4040.

Hard to say what you're doing wrong. Your original question has a lot of annotations that don't seem nessesary to reproduce the problem. Try making a truly minimal example. And then verify that multiple web drivers instance are created.

Finally, I am able to find the root cause, there's one service class that is being shared between threads and that's causing the issue, I declared that class as PROTOTYPE bean and it fixed the issue.

Congrats! This sounds like a problem the @ScenarioScope annotation was made for.
